# Youtube search input not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a youtube bot, but when I try to send keys to the search input, nothing appears... Here is the error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Here is my part of the code that have to interact with the input :

```
os.system('cls')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

print('Connection in progress... ')
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
os.system('cls')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]').click()
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
search.send_keys('python bot')
```

And here is the imports :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import os
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Try to change //*[@id="search"] to //input[@id="search"]

Comment: That does not make difference my friend :) page was not getting loaded properly and because of that he was getting that error. When we maximize the window, browser first loads the page properly and then maximizes the window. After that if you perform any action then it will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to maximize the window before you perform any action on the element. Here is the working code :) Please mark this answer as accepted if it has helped you.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cdriver, chrome_options=options)
    driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')
    driver.maximize_window()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="search"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search"]').click()
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search"]')
    search.send_keys('python bot')
```